# Can iperf tool be used for measuring the throughput of raw sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, network-programming, raw-sockets

I am using client server application using raw sockets, can I measure the throuhput between them using iperf.

Comment: both your clients & servers use raw sockets? Why do you need iperf then?

Answer (score 1):

`iperf` runs by its own in a client-server way. So I think you can not. But based on how, `iperf` works, you can add some code to your client and server and take the throughput measurements that you want.